# Need to change the language of a .xml file compared to an excel file c#

Tags: c#, xml, excel

I want to make a multi language app that uses .xml files but i want to upload a excel file and a base language file (french) and the language of the .xml file will be changed according to the ID's each word/phrase is linked to. All of the words/translations will be on the excel file before hand. So yeah just want to compare the base lang file to the excel file and then produce a new xml file with a different language.

Are there any good sites or places i could go do research on this type of project? I have been looking for a good few days now and it have found nothing really that helps me with my issue. So yeah if you could point me int he right direction i would be really grateful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic here. However, you may find better luck [SoftwareRecs.SE](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their question requirements](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are more strict than this site.

Comment: Okay thank you rene, i appreciate it :).